# How to correctly export PNG sequence with maximum quality

Tags: export, image

I have exported a PNG sequence of 100 frames from blender, I chose 16bit and 100% compressed to get high quality. When I import the PNG sequence into After effects, the PNG sequence seems to have lost its sharpness and is just a little but blurred. Is there another preferred method to export so the images don't deteriorate their quality?

Comment: You might want to check that the output png pixel resolution is exactly the pixel resolution of your after-effect project. Because any post scaling of a raster picture will introduce some blur loss of detail. See: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-becoming-blur-when-I-import-a-PNG-image-into-Adobe-After-Effects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not set it to 100% compressed, set it to 0.
Compression reduces picture quality in order to reduce file size.
Uncompressed is better.
To be honest,the design here is not as intuitive as it is in other graphics programs.

Comment: PNG is lossless image format, so I would expect this kind of compression setting only to increase compression time. What extra does Blender do that would actually affect image quality?

Comment: Wow, I had the impression the higher the compression the sharper the image would be, and the lower the quality would deteriorate. But thanks for the information!

Comment: @blenderbreath How did you get this impression? Compression in signal processing - no matter if it's audio or video or other kind of data - is always a process of encoding some information by using less bits than the original information. This way it reduces for example the dynamic range of audio signals or image color spaces, resulting in a possible loss of quality if the compression is too strong to retrieve all original information back again.